# Approach to make domain dependent content in Umbraco CMS

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

One of my clients wants a "section" in the content tree where local news articles can be created by local users (from within Umbraco) The site structure is as follows:

```
Content
     - mysite.com (Current hostname: mysite.com (english))
            - Frontpage
            - Some text page
            - Some text page
            - News
            - Local news
                 - Denmark
                      - News item 1
                 - Sweden
                      - News item 1
                 - England
                      - News item 1
                 - Norway
                      - News item 1
```

Now, on the News page they want to create a link to i.e. the swedish (Sverige) local news page, but only if a user visits their site with the domain: mysite.se and not .com which is the standard site.

What exactly would the best approach be to create this? "Problem" is that the main navigation is rendered using the mysite.com hostname which is set on the site-node in Umbraco. So if I enter the site with domain: mysite.se and I click on a menu item (i.e. the News link), I'll get "redirected" to the .com domain.

Any input is greatly appreciated! :-) Let me know if some of the above needs to be elaborated.

Thanks in advance.

All the best,

Bo

Answer (score 1):

I think I would solve this by using the build-in UrlRewrite option in Umbraco (/config/UrlRewriting.config)

First I would move the news folders outside of the root of the website if it is not neccessary to have them inside one site.

Second I would create a general newsoverview and newsdetail page in umbraco.

To make this work I would create links to the news overview and newsdetail page in this kind of form /newsdetail/title-of-my-newsitem/nodeId-of-my-newsitem.aspx

I then would let the UrlRewrite module redirect my url to the newsdetail.aspx page and add the nodeID to the querystring with this rewrite rule:

```
<add name="swedish_newsdetail_page"
 virtualUrl="^~myurl.se/news/(.*)/(.*)"
 rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString"
 destinationUrl="~myurl.se/newsdetail.aspx?nodeId=$2"
 ignoreCase="true" />
```

A similar construction can be created for the newsoverview page.

Comment: Hi Martijn, thanks for your input! :) Appreciated! Thing is, that right now they are running one site, the .com site. Sometime around they want the site to be multilingual, which is why I have the news in the site :-) Also, it has to be easy to set up for the administrator which means they don't want to mess around with config files (that would've been an easy solution :-D) So I have to think about that too..

Comment: My solutions can also work with the newsitems within one site but for me it feels more logical to move them out of the site-root. And setting up the config is just a one time action ;)

Comment: Ah, I see! I just talked it through with them and they still want to display the global news, but when a i.e. a swedish user hits the global news overview page, there needs to be a link to the swedish local news overview page. Does this make sense? :-)

Comment: This does makes sense, if the global news is on a different path / location then the local news, otherwise you can't get the url rewrite rules work correctly.